# Javascript variable declared as code and reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery enabled javascript app that has a variable that is declared as a substantial hunk of code.

```
var Listings = Spine.Controller.sub({
    TPL: Handlebars.compile( $( '#entry-template' ).html() ),
    events: //stuff
    init: function() //stuff

    //a whole bunch of functions
});
```

I want to pull this hunk of code into a separate file (as it is about 300 lines long) and load it with jquery.  However more importantly, I want to be able to use this code for two variables without resorting to copy-pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
function giveMeAName() {
    return Spine.Controller.sub({
        // massive code here
    });
}
```

Then you can include that file via jQuery as you would normally. After including, do this:

```
var Listings = giveMeAName();
var SomethingElse = giveMeAName();
```

You can also pass parameters, if the two uses of the code differ slightly.

Comment: My answer would have been the same if you weren't this fast. Have my upvote.

Comment: Sorry, @SoonDead, but I am known as The Sniper in some places ;)

Comment: This is what I tried before posting (I'm going to assume my load script is the issue now) because the function is undefined.  $.getScript('filename.js');

Comment: Anything that relies on the result of an asynchronous function like `getScript` MUST be inside the success callback of that function.